# Selenium test not handling django middleware correctly

Tags: django, python-3.x, selenium

I'm working on a Django framework and I get this error every time I successfully log in to my site. So yes incorrect login doesn't trigger it. It doesn't effect the site or my tests, but the stacktrace is just really annoying with every test. I'm using python 3 and django 2 with django-adminlte-cruds and django-guardian.

This is the full stacktrace and I have absolutely no idea what code of mine could cause this and I have looked at other posts about the same error but can't find anything that applies to my code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)   File "/home/ellen/.virtualenvs/purple_box/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return super().__call__(environ, start_response)   File "/home/ellen/.virtualenvs/purple_box/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 146, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)   File "/home/ellen/.virtualenvs/purple_box/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 62, in get_response
    return super().get_response(request)   File "/home/ellen/.virtualenvs/purple_box/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 81, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)   File "/home/ellen/.virtualenvs/purple_box/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return super().__call__(environ, start_response)   File "/home/ellen/.virtualenvs/purple_box/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 146, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)   File "/home/ellen/.virtualenvs/purple_box/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 62, in get_response
    return super().get_response(request)   File "/home/ellen/.virtualenvs/purple_box/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 81, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)   File "/home/ellen/.virtualenvs/purple_box/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return super().__call__(environ, start_response)   File "/home/ellen/.virtualenvs/purple_box/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 146, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)   File "/home/ellen/.virtualenvs/purple_box/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 62, in get_response
    return super().get_response(request)   File "/home/ellen/.virtualenvs/purple_box/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 81, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)   File "/home/ellen/.virtualenvs/purple_box/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return super().__call__(environ, start_response)   File "/home/ellen/.virtualenvs/purple_box/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 146, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)   File "/home/ellen/.virtualenvs/purple_box/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 62, in get_response
    return super().get_response(request)   File "/home/ellen/.virtualenvs/purple_box/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 81, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Please let me know how I can clarify more and if you have any tips regarding a fix. Thanks!

Edited:
My view for the homepage

```
@login_required
def base(request):
    """
    View function for home page of site.
    """

    # Render the HTML template base.html with the data in the context variable
    return render(request, 'cruds/base.html', context={},)
```

Edit2:
This happens when I execute my functional tests (Selenium) btw. It doesn't happen during my unit tests or when I log in to the site myself and check my server log...

On request:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Selenium setup - definitions.py:

```
class UserBaseSeleniumTestCase(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.testuser = User.objects.create_user(
            username='testuser', password=ROLES["testuser"])
        cls.testuser.is_active = True
        cls.testuser.save()
        cls.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        cls.browser.get(cls.live_server_url)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.browser.quit()
        super().tearDownClass()

    def login(self, username, password):
        self.browser.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url,
                               reverse_lazy("login")))
        username_input = self.browser.find_element_by_name("username")
        username_input.send_keys(username)
        password_input = self.browser.find_element_by_name("password")
        password_input.send_keys(password)
        self.browser.find_element_by_name("login").click()
```

test.py - one of the tests with the error, any test that successfully logs in gives the error:

```
class CorrectLoginTestCase(UserBaseSeleniumTestCase):
    def test_correct_login(self):
        self.login('testuser', ROLES["testuser"])
        expected_url = self.live_server_url + '/home/'
        self.assertEqual(self.browser.current_url, expected_url)
```

Comment: show ur view ,model

Comment: can u paste your login method cus it must be from there where you are getting an error here,i don't find any errors

Comment: @AbiWaqas I just have an html page with a login form and a submit button and the login is handled by django.

Comment: Please show us your `MIDDLEWARE` setting.

Comment: Looking at the stack trace, it seems to be an issue with how you have configured Django to serve static files during testing.

Comment: @solarissmoke I have added my MIDDLEWARE setting, it is just the standard setting. Am I missing anything there because I use selenium?

Comment: Looking at your stack trace, I see `self._middleware_chain(request)` is the problem. For some reason, `_middleware_chain` is `None`. I'd look to see how you're setting up the selenium tests. Can you share the test that's failing? Is it testing against a live server instance, or is selenium running in the same process as your test server?

Comment: @munk I have added my selenium setup and one of the tests with the error. So the tests aren't actually failing, it just gives the stacktrace every time I run it.

Comment: @Ellen Is the stack trace coming from your selenium process or the django server?

Comment: @munk From my selenium process, when I run my functional tests

Comment: It seems like you have your server configured correctly, but the selenium tests are relying on django but do not use the same configuration path. `manage.py` has some setup at the top that you might want to make sure runs when your selenium tests start. I don't know if that will do the trick, but it's a start.

Comment: @munk my manage.py is just standard django and I run my tests with python3 manage.py test so I don't think anything there would be the problem... the weird thing is the fact that the error doesn't occur when I do a test_incorrect_login so whenever it doesn't go past the login page.

Comment: did you solve it ? I have same annoying message although my tests passes with OK. my tests are different but I also have "self.live_server_url" where it points similar error.

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29353 there is a bug reporting which is solved about this .

Comment: @ytsejam Thanks! I'm glad I wasn't the only one. Hopefully it will merge soon and fix the problem for the both of us.